# How to debug why Nvidia-331 is not working?

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, xorg

Since today, my nvidia-331 installation is broken again.

1. The version history available from packages.ubuntu.com claims the driver itself hasn't changed:

http://packages.ubuntu.com/de/trusty/misc/nvidia-331

2. I reinstalled the package a couple times, DKMS is building everything properly.
   Still, after reboot, nothing is working.
3. nouveau and all other variants of nvidia are properly blacklisted in /etc/modprobe.d/
4. The driver writes the following to Xorg.log (/var/log/Xorg.*.log) file, stating that it falls back to old probe method for vesa and all other kernel mods (whatever that means?)

Link because code-feature is broken with Xorg logs: http://pastebin.com/ik71xXTM

5. The driver also writes to the kernel log (/var/log/kern.log.*) the following, note the invalid context error.

   NVRM: Your system is not currently configured to drive a VGA console
   NVRM: on the primary VGA device. The NVIDIA Linux graphics driver
   NVRM: requires the use of a text-mode VGA console. Use of other console
   NVRM: drivers including, but not limited to, vesafb, may result in
   NVRM: corruption and stability problems, and is not supported.
   NVRM: os_pci_init_handle: invalid context!

What else am I missing?

I had my Nvidia drivers up and running for exactly one month this year before the update of two days ago. Also, no old versions of the nvidia-331 package is available in the ubuntu archives :-/

Comment: Please add the output of `apt-cache policy nvidia-331` to your question. Also you know which version was installed before? [Here](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/restricted/n/nvidia-graphics-drivers-331/) there is a 7 and a 7.1 version (I have 7.1 in my system)